# How to save Serialized object to mongodb with spring data mongo

Tags: serialization, spring-data-mongodb

I has the spring data mongo POJO as below. Here Map has key value pairs dynamically.

```
@Document(collection = "sample_event")
public class SampleEvent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3575974453648692913L;

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    @Field("unique_id")
    private String uniqueId;

    @Field("ts")
    private Date timestamp;

    private Map<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public ObjectId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(ObjectId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUniqueId() {
        return uniqueId;
    }

    public void setUniqueId(String uniqueId) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public void setFields(Map<String, Object> obj) {
         fields = obj;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getFields() {
        return fields;
    }
}
```

I want to save the json data to mongo as below with above POJO (Here abc, xyz, lmn will get from 'fields Map'):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a02c169e68c0a19248fe023"),
    "unique_id" : "111111",
    "ts" : ISODate("2017-10-10T18:30:05.000Z"),
    "abc" : "info",
    "xyz" : "notice",
    "lmn" : "25"
}
```

But it is saving as below:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a02c169e68c0a19248fe023"),
        "unique_id" : "111111",
        "ts" : ISODate("2017-10-10T18:30:05.000Z"),
        "fields" : 
               { 
                   "abc" : "info",
                   "xyz" : "notice",
                   "lmn" : "25" 
               }
  }
```

How to remove 'fileds' attribute from nested json while saving to mongo. Please help me.

Comment: Take a look at Jackson's `@JsonAnyGetter` and `@JsonAnySetter` annotations (examples provided [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations)).

Comment: Hi @Marc Tarin I able to print the expected output on command line with '@JsonAnyGetter'  using objectmapper.writeValueAsString(obj) API. But how to save serialized object to mongodb using spring data mongo. Please help.